# Remember like value on list of post firestore android

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, viewmodel, android-livedata

So i want to show list of recent post in my post collection, My firestore database model is something like

```
post(collection)
--uid(doc)
---post_id(field)

user
--uid(doc)
--idUser(field)
```

I want show all of post on that post collection, but user can see which post that they liked on that timeline by highlight the heart icon. This something like facebook or instagram feature. My current approach is just show list of post on the collection post. like this

```
fun getListRecentPost() : LiveData<List<Post>>{
        recentPostRepo.getRecentPost()
            .orderBy("createdAt", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
            .whereEqualTo("status", 1)
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error ->
            error?.let{
                Log.e("err_get_recet_post", error.localizedMessage!!)
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }
            val addedRecentPostList = mutableListOf<Post>()
            querySnapshot?.let {
                for (document in it){
                    val post = document.toObject<Post>()
                    addedRecentPostList.add(post)
                }
                listRecenPost.value = addedRecentPostList
            }
        }
        return listRecenPost
    }
```

I tried to add one collection like this

```
liked_post(collection)
--uid(doc)
---idPost(field)
---idUser(field)
```

Then after that i tried to make `data class` like this

```
data class(var post : Post, var isLiked : Boolean)
```

Then i use nested loop

first loop is loop the post collection and second loop is loop the liked_post collection, and then I make variable isExist to fill the data class inside first loop so when the document exist on second loop isExist become true, but somehow this is not working. Here's the code to nested loop

```
fun getListLikedPost(idUser :String) : LiveData<List<LikedPostList>> {
        postRepo.getListLikedPost()
            .orderBy("createdAt", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
            .whereEqualTo("status", 1)
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error ->
                val addedRecentPostList = mutableListOf<LikedPostList>()
                error?.let{
                    Log.e("err_get_liked_post1", error.localizedMessage!!)
                }
                querySnapshot?.let {
                    for (document in querySnapshot){
                        val likedPostObj = LikedPostList()
                        var isExist = false

                        postRepo.getLikedPost().whereEqualTo("idUser", idUser).addSnapshotListener { value, error ->

                            value?.let {
                                for (likedPost in it){
                                    Log.d("likedPost", likedPost.get("idPost").toString())
                                    isExist = likedPost.get("idPost").toString() == document.get("idPost")
                                }
                            }
                            error?.let {
                                Log.e("err_get_liked_post2", error.localizedMessage!!)
                            }
                        }

                        val post = document.toObject<Post>()
                        likedPostObj.post = post
                        likedPostObj.isLiked = isExist
                        Log.d("list_liked_post1", likedPostObj.toString())
                        addedRecentPostList.add(likedPostObj)
                    }
                    listLikedPost.value = addedRecentPostList

                }
            }

        return listLikedPost
    }
```

the variable isLiked is not change it always show false (should be 1 true in my current data)

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please edit your question and add a screenshot of it. Please also add the code that you are using to loop.

Comment: It seems you solved your own question, please provide the answer to help others if they will encounter the same issue.

Comment: no i dont have solution yet, i tried to solved, i think it works but there is still bug, i will edit my question